# How to automate exec stored procedure without SQL Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, ssms-2014

I have a stored procedure in SSMS 2014 that I want to automate to run daily, but I don't have SQL Agent at my new company.  Is there a way to schedule this so I don't have to manually run the "exec spWhatever" in SQL each day?

Someone suggested a batch file, but I have no experience with creating or running those.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i run a sql query on a schedule without using sql server agent jobs( & no BI too) and pump the results in an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380360/how-can-i-run-a-sql-query-on-a-schedule-without-using-sql-server-agent-jobs-n)

Answer (score 4):

You can use sqlcmd and call stored procedure and schedule that in windows scheduler to run every day as below:

```
sqlcmd -S yourservername -E -Q "EXEC [dbo].[yourprocedure]"
```